# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function as_next_scheduled_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When I tried to update Woocommerce plugin into new version (3.6.1) I got this error

> [21-Apr-2019 20:29:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to
>   undefined function as_next_scheduled_action() in
>   /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-
>    content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/queue/class-wc-action-queue.php:127
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/marketplace-suggestions/class-wc-marketplace-updater.php(30):
>   WC_Action_Queue->get_next('woocommerce_upd...')
>       #1 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WC_Marketplace_Updater::init('')
>       #2 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
>       #3 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
>       #4 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-settings.php(505): do_action('init')
>       #5 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-config.php(79): require_once('/home/tleelxvn/...')
>       #6 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/tleelxvn/...')
>       #7 /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-cron.php(39): require_once('/home/tleelxvn/...')
>       #8 {main}
>        thrown in /home/tleelxvn/fairo.pk/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/queue/class-wc-action-queue.php
>   on line 127

Answer (score 1):

I came up against this exact problem today.  My situation may be unique, but if what I learned helps anyone, all the better.

In my situation, I have code within my theme where I'll force load WooCommerce if it isn't loaded.  The site requires WooCommerce on an AJAX call that otherwise knows nothing about WordPress.  In normal WordPress requests, the plugin is already loaded, so my code block does nothing.

However, I received this error when I stood up a new site with the same repo and I had not yet activated the WooCommerce plugin.  As soon as I activated it, the error disappeared.  The reason the error occurred is because the required file only gets included on the `plugins_loaded` action, which in my scenario had already been run by the time I force-loaded WooCommerce.